# Why do buck converter example circuits tie both the input and output grounds together?

Tags: buck

This is an example application:

---

[image: Texas Instruments TPS6300x Typical Application Circuit]

Image source: [Texas Instruments - TPS6300x High efficiency Buck-Boost Converter datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63001.pdf)

---

I don't see the point to show the input (power ground) ground and the output grounds separately and then tie them together.  Is this to assist with the PCB layout?

Comment: FWIW, both input and output ground show one and the same symbol (*chassis ground*?!). The other symbol ((Protective) earth?) shows up at the GND pin. the "bottom" of the output voltage divider and the bottom of C3. And there is a reason why the schematic doesn't spell *buck*.

Comment: ril3y - Hi, Please remember the [site rule](/help/referencing) for content copied into a post from elsewhere. In order to help, I found what I believe to be the missing source PDF link in this case and added it for you. For the future, please remember it's your responsibility to do that :) Thanks.

Comment: The question makes no sense because those circled parts are not the input and output grounds that are tied together at the chip.

Comment: Those aren't input and output grounds, they're power and signal grounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an odd schematic.  I'm pretty sure they're using the ground on the end of C3 and R2 to mean a local signal ground, while the "chassis ground" symbol on the PGND pin and the end of C1 and C2 is the board ground.

They're doing that in the expectation that the board ground may have high currents flowing through it, and that it could, in fact, have potential differences at different spots on the board.  This would mess up the chip, especially the voltage feedback.

If that data sheet has a suggested layout -- stick to it, especially around the ground connections.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't see the point to show the input (power ground) ground and the
> output grounds separately and then tie them together. Is this to
> assist with the PCB layout? Thanks!

I think the intention was to show that they need to be tied together, the thing that matters is where they are tied together as the GND shouldn't carry the majority of currents.

But mainly this is a problem for the feedback voltage loop, if the return current to the battery is shifting the ground then there would be issues, I think they just want the user to be aware of the common mode voltage problems.

The recommended layout doesn't really separate the PGND, but they do have a massive ground so parasitic wouldn't generate a lot of common mode voltage.

I'd just use the recommended layout.

Answer (score 0):

That's not input and output grounds.  Notice the ground symbol ties to VINA and GND, and not VIN, VOUT or PGND, which are tied with the earth symbol.

The intention is to show a local *analog ground*.  Most regulators name this specifically, and have a layout detail to the effect.

A typical layout is given later in this datasheet, though it makes no reference  to the local bypass scheme.  Despite the proceeding paragraph mentioning it.

Sometimes the evaluation board can be illuminating: 
https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slvu156/slvu156.pdf?ts=1684812919710 
This appears to be the source of their layout screenshot.  No additional explanation is given.

The net separation appears to be this part:

[image: Layout with ground region highlighted]

That they added soldermask to these layers, doesn't exactly help reading connectivity here.  It turns out there's one pixel of gray between pins 8 and EP, showing they are shorted under the chip.

I would not recommend the large signal ground hanging off as an antenna.  Notice the left and right GND regions have no connectivity except under the chip (top layer) and along the top edge of the board (bottom layer).  That is, what could be a solid pour closing a loop around the regulator, is instead cut up into left and right halves by the signal traces and jumpers.  Likely there is some ~mV of common mode noise between left and right grounds; it would be easily avoided by fully connecting these pours.

Fortunately, in a real application, you are unlikely to need the jumper blocks, and the signal traces can be kept local, or stitched around with vias.  A 4+ layer board (inner GND plane) also solves the issue.

It is unfortunate that this isn't clarified by the datasheet itself.  This datasheet is par for the course, as far as modern TI documentation goes.  During my career, I've very much seen their quality decline overall; not just in terms of documentation, but also bugs in new devices, lack of communication between engineering and marketing departments, etc..  Make of this what you will.